# Form submit, Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

If i submit form in such way:

***HTML***

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="test_url">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="">
  <input type="button" onclick="this.form.submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
  alert('ok');
  return false;
});
```

Can I prevent submission with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('ok');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SKEPM/5/)**

passing event argument (here, `e`) to submit callback you can stop form submission using **[`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)** method.

From jQuery doc about `.preventDefault()`:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be
>   triggered.

#### Note

Change

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form.submit" value="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, just passing the event along with the handler and using `preventDefault()` method

```
$('#form').submit(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   alert('ok');
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/